# Design In-Memory File System - Python - Trie - Leetcode Error

Tags: python, trie

I am trying to solve the below leetcode problem

**Design a data structure that simulates an in-memory file system.**

Implement the FileSystem class:

FileSystem() Initializes the object of the system.
List ls(String path)
If path is a file path, returns a list that only contains this file's name.
If path is a directory path, returns the list of file and directory names in this directory.
The answer should in lexicographic order.
void mkdir(String path) Makes a new directory according to the given path. The given directory path does not exist. If the middle directories in the path do not exist, you should create them as well.
void addContentToFile(String filePath, String content)
If filePath does not exist, creates that file containing given content.
If filePath already exists, appends the given content to original content.
String readContentFromFile(String filePath) Returns the content in the file at filePath.

Example 1:

Input

```
["FileSystem", "ls", "mkdir", "addContentToFile", "ls", "readContentFromFile"]
[[], ["/"], ["/a/b/c"], ["/a/b/c/d", "hello"], ["/"], ["/a/b/c/d"]]
```

Output

```
[null, [], null, null, ["a"], "hello"]
```

Explanation

```
FileSystem fileSystem = new FileSystem();
fileSystem.ls("/");                         // return []
fileSystem.mkdir("/a/b/c");
fileSystem.addContentToFile("/a/b/c/d", "hello");
fileSystem.ls("/");                         // return ["a"]
fileSystem.readContentFromFile("/a/b/c/d"); // return "hello"
```

**Below is the code I have written for it**

```
class FileSystem:

def __init__(self):
    self.root = {}

def ls(self, path: str) -> List[str]:
    path = path.split('/')
    node = self.root
    for char in path:
        if char in node:
            node = node[char]
    print(node)
    node = list(node)
    print(node)
    print(path)
    return sorted(node)

def mkdir(self, path: str) -> None:
    path = path.split('/')
    node = self.root
    for char in path:
        if char not in node:
            node[char] = {}
        node = node[char]
        
 

def addContentToFile(self, filePath: str, content: str) -> None:
    node = self.root
    filePath = filePath.split('/')
    for char in filePath:
        if char not in node:
            node[char] = {}
        node = node[char]
    node[content] = '*'

    
def readContentFromFile(self, filePath: str) -> str:
    node = self.root
    filePath = filePath.split('/')
    for char in filePath:
        if char not in node:
            return "Error"
        node = node[char]
    result_list = list(node.keys())

    return "".join(result_list)
```

**Here is an input I am struggling with**

```
["FileSystem","mkdir","ls","ls","mkdir","ls","ls","addContentToFile","ls","ls","ls"]
[[],["/goowmfn"],["/goowmfn"],["/"],["/z"],["/"],["/"],["/goowmfn/c","shetopcy"],["/z"],["/goowmfn/c"],["/goowmfn"]]
```

**Here is the expected output:**

```
[null,null,[],["goowmfn"],null,["goowmfn","z"],["goowmfn","z"],null,[],["c"],["c"]]
```

**Here is my incorrect output**

```
[null,null,[],["goowmfn"],null,["goowmfn","z"],["goowmfn","z"],null,[],["shetopcy"],["c"]]
```

I believe the issue comes in when I am not able to return the name of the file for a ls statement but instead return the content of the statement

How do I ensure that when the ls method is run I return the file name or contents in the path not the file contents?

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Titles should summarize the question; posts should clearly **ask a question**, ideally a *specific* question that starts with a question word like "why" or "how and ends with a question mark (`?`). "Help with this would be greatly appreciated" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). We are not interested in greetings and thanks. We *are* interested in your analysis of the problem - don't just show your debug trace output; tell us *what you think it implies*.

Comment: Don't just show us correct and incorrect output; explain *your assessment* of *how* the incorrect output is incorrect; and explain, in your own words, *your best guess as to why* the incorrect output occurs, based on your attempts at [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Try to isolate the problem in a [mre]; how do we use the class to attempt to solve the problem? Will all of these methods be used? Don't just show us the specification for the task; explain what *problem* you are trying to solve by asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Made the changes you recommended. Thanks guys. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The way you encode a *file* in the data structure makes it hard to distinguish it from a *directory* with the same name. Moreover, you define the content of the file as if it were a subdirectory of the "file". It will be easier to work with, if you define the file not as a dictionary, but as its own type (like the instance of a `File` class). That way it can be easily recognised and its content can be an attribute.

Here the code updated with that idea on encoding a file.

At the same time, I also:

- Subclassed `FileSystem` from `dict`, so it does not need a `root` attribute.
- Defined a separate method for walking down a path -- since that is what almost every other method must do, and so we avoid code repetition. Extra arguments to this method will determine whether missing directories should be created automatically, or an error should be thrown, and what the path is supposed to point at (a file, a directory, or either)
- Defined a class `File` with name and content.

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, name, content=""):
        self.name = name
        self.content = content
        
class FileSystem(dict):

    def walk(self, path: str, autocreate: bool=False, expected: str="any") -> Union['FileSystem', File]:
        if not path.startswith("/"):
            raise ValueError("Path should start with slash")
        path = path[1:]
        if path.endswith("/"):
            path = path[:-1]
        child = self
        directories = path.split("/") if path else []
        path = ""
        for i, directory in enumerate(directories):
            path += "/" + directory
            parent = child
            if not directory in parent:
                if not autocreate:
                    raise ValueError(f"Invalid path: '{path}'")
                # auto create entry
                parent[directory] = File(directory) if i == len(directories) - 1 and expected == "file" else FileSystem()
            child = parent[directory]
        if expected != "any" and (expected == "file") != isinstance(child, File):
            raise ValueError(f"'{path}' is not a {expected}")
        return child
        
    def ls(self, path: str) -> List[str]:
        node = self.walk(path)
        return sorted(node) if isinstance(node, FileSystem) else [node.name]
    
    def mkdir(self, path: str) -> None:
        self.walk(path, True, "directory")
                     
    def addContentToFile(self, filePath: str, content: str) -> None:
        self.walk(filePath, True, "file").content += content
            
    def readContentFromFile(self, filePath: str) -> str:
        return self.walk(filePath, False, "file").content
```